# OLD Javascript code document.formID.ElementID Not worling in .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

My Project is having a number of **.NET applications(aspx)** developed in .NET **Framework 3.5** and hosted under **single domain(Common Virtual directory**) to share session.

Now I have developed (aspx) applications in .NET Framework 4.5 and deployed in the same Virtual directory and switched the IIS settings to use 4.5 Framework in Integrated mode. So, all old and new applications run in Framework 4.5.

**The problem is  one old javascript syntax are not supported.**

***Old Syntax:***

```
document.frmUser.txtLogin.value = document.frmUser.txtRequired.value;
```

above code assign the text box value of txtRequired to txtLogin. Both are inside the form tag with ID frmUser.

The ***newer syntax*** for this is:

```
document.getElementbyID("txtLogin").value = document.getElementbyID(".txtRequired").value;
```

But I am not allowed to change the old application code.

Is there any possibility to make it work **without changing the code**. Any workaround to fix it, by adding **additional** IIS or any other **settings**???

Comment: I guess install and use an old browser? The old syntax doesn't work because it wasn't standard compliant but was supported by old browsers...

Comment: I checked in IE 6. Not worked. The problem is faced instantly after the Virtual directory moved from 3.5 to .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: @Kumar I cannot imagine this issue to be a .NET framework issue but rather a 'browser/Doc Type' issue.

Comment: The old syntax is supported by IE all versions. Also when I revert the IIS settings back to 3.5 all the old applications works fine. What cause such issue??